# Is there a Future.sequence analog in kotlin?

Tags: scala, kotlin, future, completable-future

In scala you can "map" collection of futures to future of collection like that:

```
val l: List[Future[String]]  = List(Future {"1"}, Future {"2"})
val x: Future[List[String]] = Future.sequence(l)
```

How to same thing but with kotlin?

Comment: When downvoting please post a comment.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you use coroutines:

```
val l: List<Deferred<String>>  = (1..2).map {i -> async(Unconfined){ "$i" }}
val x: Deffered<List<String>> = async(Unconfined) { l.map {it.await()} }
```

Comment: If you have to use `CompletebleFuture` due to Java interop, then you can convert `List<CompletableFuture<String>>` to `CompletableFuture<List<String>>` using virtually the same code, just replacing `async` builder with `future` builder from `kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8`